# Error de Sintaxis en script mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$consulta = DB::Select('
    SELECT nombrePerfilCargo, idPerfilCargo,porcentajeCargoHabilidad,porcentajeHabilidadCargo,c.Compania_idCompania
    FROM cargo c
    LEFT JOIN  cargohabilidad ch
    ON c.idCargo = ch.Cargo_idCargo
    LEFT JOIN perfilcargo pc
    ON ch.PerfilCargo_idPerfilCargo = pc.idPerfilCargo
    WHERE idCargo = '.$idCargo  and 'c.Compania_idCompania = '.\Session::get('idCompania'));
```

¿Alguien me puede decir cómo es la sintaxis luego de la primera condición del `WHERE` para adicionar una segunda `AND`...

```
WHERE idCargo = '.$idCargo  and 'c.Compania_idCompania = '.\Session::get('idCompania'));
```

para adicionar el `Session::get`?

Es que me aparece un error de sintaxis:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1 (SQL: 1)

Comment: El error y la solución no tienen nada que ver con Laravel, si quieres lo discutimos en un chat @sstan , de hecho es un error relacionado con sintaxis de PHP.

Comment: @Shaz: Ah perfecto, solo faltaba la etiqueta `PHP` entonces. No cuestionaba lo de la etiqueta de Laravel, yo no sé nada en cuanto a eso. Solo que me parecía raro que quedara solo la etiqueta de MySQL. Gracias.

Comment: Te aconsejo que reviertas el título de tu pregunta y quites el "(Cerrada)". No sólo no es necesario indicarlo pues se entiende que una pregunta está resuelta cuando se ha aceptado una respuesta, sino que además puede ser confuso: En Stack Overflow una pregunta se marca como "[cerrada]" cuando se considera que no es apropiada para el sitio (cuando es muy amplia y no tiene una respuesta concreta, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que construiste mal el string de la consulta (dejaste el `AND` fuera). Debería ser así:

```
$consulta = DB::Select(' SELECT nombrePerfilCargo, idPerfilCargo, porcentajeCargoHabilidad,
    porcentajeHabilidadCargo, c.Compania_idCompania
    FROM cargo c LEFT JOIN cargohabilidad ch ON c.idCargo = ch.Cargo_idCargo
    LEFT JOIN perfilcargo pc ON ch.PerfilCargo_idPerfilCargo = pc.idPerfilCargo 
    WHERE idCargo = '.$idCargo.' AND c.Compania_idCompania = '.\Session::get('idCompania'));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias se me había pasado por alto

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema está en la construcción con las comas. Creo que `'.$idCargo and 'c.Compania_idCompania = '` debería ser `'.$idCargo .'and c.Compania_idCompania = '`

Comment: intente como dices y persiste el error de sintaxis

Comment: tiene que haber un espacio entre .' y el and (que no lo he puesto)

Answer (score 2):

Proba sacando el AND de adentro del string.

```
WHERE idCargo = '.$idCargo ' and c.Compania_idCompania = '.\Session::get('idCompania'))';
```

Comment: Si lo saco dentro del string me sale este error 
syntax error, unexpected '' and c.Compania_idCompania = ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: WHERE idCargo = '.$idCargo' and c.Compania_idCompania = '.\Session::get('idCompania'))'; 
Proba de nuevo con esta faltaba una tilde al final del ultimo string

Comment: Ahi edite mi respuesta anterior volve a probar con eso! Faltaba tambien el espacio antes del and